# Persistent Header for web page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have looked at several jQuery methods of making a persistent header, but I really don't understand how the functions work.

The basis of my idea being, have a drop down menu somewhere on a page and when the top of the screen gets to its position, change the drop down menu to a fixed position at the top...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have it in principle. You'll want to look at [`window.onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll) and [`element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollTop) to help drive things...

Comment: There are hundreds of examples, and thousands of resources for this.  What specifically is your question....

Comment: @Axel I guess just really a pointer in the right direction. If you have good examples or anything that I could possibly use to my advantage.

Comment: So you want me to Google examples & solutions for you?

Comment: Do you honestly think I didn't Google it before posting here? Sometimes people know of good pages that don't always appear on Google. 

But regardless, one of the things that I am a little bit confused about, that Google hasn't helped me with, is if I want to make a separate file with my jQuery script, similar to what I do for Javascript, how do I handle importing the jQuery libraries? Also, how can I import it to my HTML page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/C5nXH/

HTML

```
<div class="test">Hello!</div>
```

jQuery

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    offset = $('.test').offset();
    if ( offset.top < $( window ).scrollTop() + 10 ){
        $('.test').addClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
body{
    height: 2000px;
}

.test{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}

.test.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: So now in order to get it so that when I scroll back up it will return to its starting position when I pass it would I have to have variables that track the starting position and put another if statement?

Comment: Here's an updated version with the scroll back http://jsfiddle.net/C5nXH/1/

Comment: Thanks! Does any of the background stuff matter or was that just to make it easier to see?

Comment: The background is just to show the scroll.

Comment: And now for implementation do I need to import any libraries?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work for me... http://jsfiddle.net/CdMD7/

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in the left panel http://jsfiddle.net/lefoy/CdMD7/1/